# Access next sibling <li> element with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am completely new to web parsing with Python/BeautifulSoup. I have an HTML that has (part of) the code as follows:

```
<div id="pages">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="example.com">Example</a></li>
        <li><a href="example.com">Example</a></li>
        <li><a href="example1.com">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="example2.com">Example 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have to visit **each link** (basically each `<li>` element) until there are no more `<li>` tags present. Each time a link is clicked, its corresponding `<li>` element gets class as 'active'. My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

landingPage = urllib2.urlopen('somepage.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(landingPage)

pageList = soup.find("div", {"id": "pages"})

page = pageList.find("li", {"class": "active"})
```

This code gives me the first `<li>` item in the list. My logic is I am keeping on checking if the `next_sibling` is not None. If it is not None, I am creating an HTTP request to the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag in that sibling `<li>`. That would get me to the next page, and so on, till there are no more pages.

But I can't figure out how to get the `next_sibling` of the `page` variable given above. Is it `page.next_sibling.get("href")` or something like that? I looked through the documentation, but somehow couldn't find it. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) and be explicit about what sibling element do you want to find:

```
next_li_element = page.find_next_sibling("li")
```

`next_li_element` would become `None` if the `page` corresponds to the last active `li`:

```
if next_li_element is None:
    # no more pages to go
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at `dir(page)` or the documentation? If so, how did you miss `.find_next_sibling()`?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

landingPage = urllib2.urlopen('somepage.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(landingPage)

pageList = soup.find("div", {"id": "pages"})

page = pageList.find("li", {"class": "active"})
sibling = page.find_next_sibling()
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I should have seen it in the documentation. Actually, web parsing is totally new to me and I'm feeling a bit lost.