# how to get next tag(element) of the selected tag in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want an element that has only HTML tag, not any unique identification
but I can select the upper tag of that tag, how can I get next tag form that selection
**(e.g.)**

```
<div>
    <span class="class1"> text </span>
    <p> I want this text </P> <!-- how to get this text --> 
</div>
```

**code i tried**

```
data = BeautifulSoup("""
    <div>
        <span class="class1"> text </span>
        <p> I want this text </P> <!-- how to get this text -->
    </div>
    """, 'lxml')

data.find('span', class_='class1').next_sibling
data.find('span', class_='class1').next_element
```

**Output:**

```
'\n'
' text '
```

Comment: what you tried show some code you can use .next_sibling  in beautiful soup get next tag(element) of the selected tag in beautifulsoup

Comment: @ravishankarchavare id tried next_sibling, next_element but not working

Comment: @ggorlen code added to the question that I tried

Comment: Thanks. Try `data.find('span', class_='class1').find_next_sibling()`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141342/6243352). Call `.text` on it if you want to extract the text.

Comment: @ggorlen yeah it's working. you can put it as a answer.  thanks for efforts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`.find_next_sibling()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
data.find('span', class_='class1').find_next_sibling()
```

Use `.text` if you'd like to extract the text from the `NavigableString` object.